# We want to know which type of design users like the most to focus on

Tags: sentence

Is this sentence correct?

> We want to know which type of design users like the most to focus on.

Comment: What do you expect the sentence to mean?

Comment: Would 'We want to know which type of design users prefer' do, ali?

Comment: This question would be better asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Your text would be more idiomatically expressed as *We want to know which type of design users **most like** to focus on*, but I think you've got a bit confused anyway - the intended *meaning* is more likely to be  *We want to know which type of design users like best, **so we can focus on that***.

Comment: If users like a, we will work on it

Comment: You've created an "awkward" utterance - you're trying to collapse together ***wanting to know** the most favoured design* AND ***focusing** on that design*, but the word AND doesn't appear at all in your version.